# Would this Arch Wiki fix for enabling GPU apply to Ubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 16.10, hybrid-graphics

So, I have a razer blade 2016 QHD+ with an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060. I am using Ubuntu 16.10. I have a problem where when the discrete gpu is disabled, my computer won't boot. I was wondering if I could apply [this](https://github.com/m4ng0squ4sh/razer_blade_14_2016_acpi_fix) fix on the arch wiki without breaking anything. If so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the ACPI firmware fix can be applied in a similar fashion to Ubuntu. The [boot configuration](https://github.com/m4ng0squ4sh/razer_blade_14_2016_acpi_fix#final-configuration) works differently though because Ubuntu 16.10 uses Grub instead of systemd-boot.

1. Install build tools:

   ```sh
   sudo apt install git make cpio acpica-tools
   ```
2. Clone the Git repository:

   ```sh
   git clone git@github.com:m4ng0squ4sh/razer_blade_14_2016_acpi_fix.git
   cd razer_blade_14_2016_acpi_fix
   ```
3. Build and install the ACPI firmware fix:

   ```sh
   sudo make all
   sudo make install
   ```
4. To set up the fix adjust `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`. Look for a line like

   ```sh
   initrd ${rel_dirname}/${initrd}
   ```

   and insert this line before it:

   ```sh
   initrd ${rel_dirname}/razer_acpi_fix.img
   ```
5. Run `sudo update-grub` to apply the changes and reboot.

P.S.: I haven't actually tested this but it should work from what I can tell based on the build scripts and boot configuration instructions for Arch Linux. I'd be happy work out any kinks in these instructions together with you.